# On the nearest integer to $\zeta(1-1/B),B \ge 2$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Let $B \ge 2$ be integer and $[x]$ denote the nearest integer
to real $x$.

For $2 \le B \le 10^5$ computations with mpmath suggest:

$$ [\zeta(1-1/B)]=-B+1 \qquad (1)$$

Is (1) true for all $B \ge 2$?

Comment: $\zeta(1+x)=\frac{1}{x}+\gamma+o(1)$.

Comment: @Wojowu Many thanks, I suppose this would require some additional effort to get rid of $+\gamma$.

Comment: You don't want to get rid of it - when the $o(1)$ term gets small enough, this implies $\frac{1}{x}<\zeta(1+x)<\frac{1}{x}+1$. To see that it is good enough for $B\geq 2$ would require an explicit estimate on $o(1)$ which I will leave to someone else.

Comment: @Wojowu I suspect the nearest integer might be outside the bounds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can make the error mentioned by Wojowu in his comment explicit by using some results on the Laurent coefficients of the zeta function. There are a few results on this, but I'll just use Theorem 2 of [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/rocky-mountain-journal-of-mathematics/volume-2/issue-1/On-the-Hurwitz-zeta-function/10.1216/RMJ-1972-2-1-151.full) by Berndt (which gives a more general result for the Hurwitz zeta function). The relevant result is

**Theorem.** (Berndt) *Write*
$$
\zeta(s) = \frac{1}{s-1} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \gamma_n (s-1)^n
$$
*for the Laurent series expansion of $\zeta$ around $s=1$. Then for $n\geq 1$, we have*
$$
\left|\gamma_n\right| \leq \frac{4}{n\pi^n}.
$$
For $B\geq 2$ an integer, write
$$
\zeta\left(1-\frac{1}{B}\right) = -B + \gamma + R(B),
$$
where $\gamma=\gamma_0\approx .577...$ is the usual Euler-Mascheroni constant and
$$
R(B) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \gamma_n \left(-\frac{1}{B}\right)^n.
$$
Applying the triangle inequality and Berndt's result, we have
$$
\left|R(B)\right| \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4}{n(B\pi)^n} \leq \frac{4}{B}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\pi^n}.
$$
The sum on the right converges rapidly and is numerically $\approx 0.383...$. Thus
$$
\left| R(B) \right| \leq \frac{2}{B}.
$$
(By a more careful analysis, the constant 2 can be replaced with 1.) For $B \geq 26$, it follows that
$$
\frac{1}{2} < \gamma+ R(B) < 1.
$$
Therefore
$$
\left[ \zeta\left(1-\frac{1}{B} \right) \right] = -B+1
$$
for $B \geq 26$.  The remaining cases can be verified via computer.

Comment: Fractional parts seem to decrease, this might suggest a proof working for these cases too...$$\begin{array}{rl}1 & -0.5 \\
 2 & -1.46035 \\
 3 & -2.44758 \\
 4 & -3.44129 \\
 5 & -4.43754 \\
 6 & -5.43505 \\
 7 & -6.43328 \\
 8 & -7.43196 \\
 9 & -8.43093 \\
 10 & -9.43011 \\
 11 & -10.4294 \\
 12 & -11.4289 \\
 13 & -12.4284 \\
 14 & -13.428 \\
 15 & -14.4277 \\
 16 & -15.4274 \\
 17 & -16.4271 \\
 18 & -17.4268 \\
 19 & -18.4266 \\
 20 & -19.4264 \\
 21 & -20.4263 \\
 22 & -21.4261 \\
 23 & -22.426 \\
 24 & -23.4258 \\
 25 & -24.4257 \\
 26 & -25.4256\end{array}$$

Comment: (In fact these fractional parts seem to monotonously converge to $1-\gamma$)

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე In problems like these where explicit estimates are needed, there's always a balance to strike between technical simplicity and range of applicability. I'm sure there's a proof that works for these small values, but it's (likely) not going to be as neat as the method I used. Such technical scruples would probably only obscure or complicate the analysis, rather than simplifying it. Since there are so few exceptional cases to check, I think technical simplicity and aesthetically pleasing inequalities are preferable to having a wider range of applicability.